# htaccess, directadmin vhost and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directadmin

i have task to create connect to wordpress by default https with wwww in url

```
 #Require SSL
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

but this configuration dont working. Maybe httpd.conf or directadmin.confg have some flag/configuration for this?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33657097/5397119) will be useful for you. There described how to configure SSL in linux apache.

Comment: btw, when you write "something not working" please, add error messages to your question(for example, from apache error.log) or describe what happened(and also add apache error.log).

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. My error is just [code]TOO_MUCH_REDIRECT[/code] in web browser